# Check if $modal is open similar to $dialog.isOpen

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, migration, angular-bootstrap

I'm migrating from AngularJS 1.1.15 to 1.3.15 and my current issue is getting $modal to work instead of $dialog.

If anyone has any helpful links regarding the migration would be appreciated :) I'm currently handling it per-bug fix.

To my current question:
My previous code was looking like:

```
var msgBox = $dialog.dialog({ ... });
msgBox.open().then(......);
```

And I changed it to

```
var msgBox = $modal.open(...);
msgBox.opened.then(......);
```

So now the issue i'm experiencing is having an IF:

```
if (msgBox && msgBox.isOpen())
```

How do I implement it with $modal? From the [documentation here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) I don't see there is a replacement for isOpen.

On most stackoverflow questions I saw people suggesting to use jQuery, but its pretty messy and I rather avoid that.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any "out of the box" solution for this, so I'm checking if a $modal is opened or closed by checking the statuses from the `$modal.result` promise. Here they are:

- Pending (0)
- Resolved (1)
- Rejected (2)

You can check if a modal is open like this:

```
$modal.result.$$state.status === 1;
```

When you close it, the `status` changes to `2`.

Hope it helps.